# How to write decode() function in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
select city,
case when city in('Tokyo','Toronto')
then 'Pune'
else 'No_change'
end New_City
from locations;
```

How do we write the above query in `decode()` in oracle?
Used locations table given in `oracle 11g`.
I tried but can't succeed.
Plz reply.

Comment: Leave it the way it is.  What you have is much more readable than decode.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do multiple checks in `DECODE()` like you are checking for 'Tokyo' and 'Toronto' in one go in the `CASE` statement. In case, if your list is longer, its best you use `CASE` statement.

--Sorry, had to add answer as I cant comment :(

Answer (score 1):

```
select decode(city, 'Tokyo', 'Pune', 'Toronto', 'Pune', 'No_change') New_City
 from locations
```

Answer (score 0):

In `decode()`, the first argument is the input. Then there are arguments that come in pairs matching input values to output values. Then the last argument is the default output.

```
select
  city,
  decode(city,
    'Tokyo', 'Pune',
    'Toronto', 'Pune',
    'No_change'
  ) as New_City
from locations;
```

Comment: but where we have used IN clause??

Comment: There isn't any place for an `IN` clause in a `DECODE`. Repeating `'Pune'` in the argument list is the cost of doing the translation you asked for. Maybe you were better off with the `CASE`.

Answer (score 0):

Decode is basically "if, then, else"

decode(If,Then,If,Then,If,Then,else)

so..

```
select (city,'Tokyo','pune','Toronto','pune','No_change')...
```

or perhaps

```
select (city,'Tokyo','pune','Toronto','pune',city)...
```

which will literally not change the city unless it's Tokyo or Toronto.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
               City as Before
              decode( instr(','||'Tokyo,Toronto'||',',  ','||City||','),
                            0,'No_Change', -- probably the `city` column itself?!
                            'Pune') as After
FROM your_table;
```

Not a nice plan, the restriction is 4000 characters only!
But just still, I tried it out of curiosity and fun!

Added `comma` before and after to enable search easily and match exactly!